# Get-PnPList cmdlet not returning anything

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, sharepoint-list, powershell-script

I'm trying to retrieve information from two columns on a sharepoint list in order to use them in powershell. Here's my code so far:

```
    $SiteURL = "https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxxx/"
    
    #Connect to PNP Online
    $creds = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "xxxxxxx" 
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://xxxxx-admin.sharepoint.com/ -Credentials $creds
     
    #Get a list by name
    $FetchList = Get-PnPList -Identity Lists/xxxxxxx
    
    #sharepoint online pnp powershell get list items 
    $ListItems = (Get-PnPListItem -List $FetchList -Fields "Host").FieldValues

 
#Loop through each Item
foreach($ListItem in $ListItems)
{  
    Write-Host "Title:" $ListItem["Title"] 
}
```

The loop should be printing the values on the column "Host", but it's not printing anything.
And my problem is, the Get-PnPList keeps returning null, meaning I'm getting no output while I'm looping through everything. I've tried using list id, list name, everything and it always returns null. Am I missing something? I'm creating this in an Azure runbook.
I even tried to simply invoke Get-PnPList with no arguments, which [according to the documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnplist?view=sharepoint-ps) for that cmdlet it should return every single available list for that website, but it still returns null (I tried printing the output which should have been a Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List object, but nothing appears).
I can confirm the $SiteURL is correct because I used powerautomate which auto-completes to the correct URL.

Thank you.

Comment: Here's the error I'm getting:
https://prnt.sc/wofidg

Comment: You are connecting to the **Admin** site instead of the site set in variable $SiteURL. Change it and try again

Comment: Hi Matiur. I tried in my local Powershell ISE and the code works there, but not in Azure. The only difference is that I used input credentials on my local PS instead of using Get-AutomationPSCredential. But I checked the credential and it's the same one I'm using locally

Answer (score 0):

Matiur's answer was correct. I was in fact connecting to the tenant/admin page instead of the correctg subpage. Thank you.